# SSRS 2012 Failure sending mail: The report server has encountered a configuration error

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm junior DBA, well actually i'm more of a sysadmin than a DBA. 
I'm struggling with a reccuring problem in one of my SQL 2012 Dev reporting server. We've reports snapshot generated by dynamics CRM 2013 on the dev reporting server. 
I've been ask to send those reports to a specific email address on which would be attached the generated report in pdf. 
I'm able to scheddule a subscription to run for example every day at the certain time and the plan did execute well. 
My problem is that the action is it supposed to trigger (sending an email) is not giving me the result i'm expecting. 
I found in the report server LogFiles some intriging entries that, despite googling them around, haven't been able to resolved. The Log entries look like this:

```
schedule!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Handling Event             TimedSubscription with data cf25ffaa-99c8-404f-bbf8-00c10ecbbe9b.
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Schedule f81461ea-5067-    4d14-b2ad-6930ce8ad3d8 executed at 06/20/2014 14:35:01.
schedule!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Creating Time based     subscription notification for subscription: cf25ffaa-99c8-404f-bbf8-00c10ecbbe9b
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Schedule f81461ea-5067-    4d14-b2ad-6930ce8ad3d8 execution completed at 06/20/2014 14:35:01.
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Initializing     EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server system properties.
notification!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Handling     subscription cf25ffaa-99c8-404f-bbf8-00c10ecbbe9b to report {f48fd9a9-4df8-e311-a000-   00155d060421}, owner: DOMAIN\Username, delivery extension: Report Server Email.
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO:     RenderForNewSession('/DEV_MSCRM/CustomReports/{f48fd9a9-4df8-e311-a000-00155d060421}')
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 5; possible reason - service account doesn't have rights to check domain user SIDs.,     Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The     report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Initializing EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server system properties.
emailextension!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: e ERROR: Error sending     email. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.  --->    Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
notification!WindowsService_203!1764!06/20/2014-14:35:01:: i INFO: Notification 4718cbfe-0fef-481b-b0dd-60fae64c4271 completed.  Success: True, Status: Failure sending mail: The report server has encountered a configuration error. Mail will not be resent., DeliveryExtension: Report Server Email, Report: {f48fd9a9-4df8-e311-a000-00155d060421}, Attempt 0
```

Can any one of you guys, faced such a problem? Would you mind pointing me out to the direction that i could follow to get the email sending working?

Thanks again for you time.

Comment: Have you looked at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842423? Seems to peg your exact issue.